# Force Google Chrome to ask before update

Tags: google-chrome

Google chrome updates to new version without asking for permission to do so. How to tame Google Chrome to be polite and ask before it plays with my Windows 7 machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot make Google Chrome ask you before update, not anymore. All you can do is to [disable automatic updates](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/9/10/Google-Chrome.-updates-without-asking) completely and then update manually. Looks like silent update is the feature [since 2008](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2008/9/10/Google-Chrome.-updates-without-asking).